# Delete script SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is a situation that I am trying to resolve. I have a table that is loaded with duplicates. It happened because similar rows were loaded from two different sources. That is being taken care of in the package.

But I want to delete those rows which are duplicates. There is no key attribute here (I can't use no PK). The two **sources** are Cleveland City and Ohio State. And I have a column that shows from which source the row was loaded from (`DataSource` column).

Thus in the row it shows as `DataSource = 'Cleveland'` or `DataSource = 'OhioState'`.

Below is a sample which I am stuck with. Could you guys have a different approach to delete those rows mine doesn't seem to be working well? Thanks again guys .. I don't think the way I am trying to approach is even correct...

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Ohio') IS NOT NULL 
     BEGIN 
     DROP TABLE #Ohio
     END 

  ;WITH Oh AS 
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER
      (
        PARTITION by UID,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,Zip
          ORDER BY 
            UID
       ) AS IA,UID,ADDRESS,City,State,Zip FROM F_staRes
     ) 
    SELECT * INTO #Ohio   FROM Oh WHERE IA> 1   AND  DataSource='Ohio'  

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Clevland') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
   DROP TABLE #Clevland
   END 

    ;WITH Cle AS 
     ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER
      (
           PARTITION by UID,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,Zip
       ORDER BY 
        UID
         ) AS CE,UID,ADDRESS,City,State,Zip FROM F_staRes
         ) 
   SELECT * INTO #Clevland   FROM Cle WHERE CE> 1  AND  DataSource!='Ohio' 

    select * from #Clevland--I want to delete this records
     Intersect 
     select * from #Ohio
```

Comment: How about copy the data with a distinct clause to another table/database and the drop the original. Maybe not an option?

Comment: @daniel_aren,I appreciate your reply,but its got an attribute which is not comparable with distinct actually.Thanks again..

Comment: Maybe this link could help. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the key word INTERSECT isn't used properly. The explanation is below. You could follow the link to get detail.

EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.
INTERSECT returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand

http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms188055.aspx

1. To achieve your perpose, you could try the command merge.

   ```
   ;
   merge into #Clevland as target
   using  #Ohio as source
   on (target.UID = source.UID) -- you could add ADDRESS,City,State,Zip
   when not matched
      insert into target (UID) values (source.UID)
   ;
   ```

Wish this will help.

Comment: ,Thanks again for the urgent reply.I found out that I have a lot of joins more than 8  tables joined to this F table,another thing I want to delete those records that are already loaded from Ohio,and became duplicates when a load from Clev was done.(This is very important)I appreciate your insights...Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID, ADDRESS, City, State, Zip, DataSource ORDER BY UID) AS Dup
  FROM dbo.F_staRes
  )
DELETE cte
WHERE Dup > 1
```

Comment: Fedoren,Thank you for your reply,but this will delete all of them,but what I want to delete is those duplicates that resulted from the city load,and i found out it involves alot of joins..Hey guys could you still  have alook at this,Thanks again guys