# Duplicate in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete script SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904087/delete-script-sql-server-2008)

Here is a situation that I am trying to resolve. I have a table that is loaded with duplicates. It happened because similar rows were loaded from two or more different sources. That is being taken care of in the package.

But I want to delete those rows which are duplicates. There is no key attribute here. Example of the sources are `Cleveland City` and `Ohio State`. And I have a column that shows from which source the row was loaded from (`DataSource` column).

Thus in the row it shows as `DataSource = 'Cleveland'` or `DataSource = 'Ohio'`.

I want to keep those records that resulted to be duplicates when they got loaded from Ohio. Its 100k records I may have to use joins. And one more thing my main table is joined with other four or five tables with `rId` which is unique for each row, that's why you see me joining with this tables and I DO NOT think I did it right.

Could you check my work guys? I **really** appreciate it.

```
 --Delete ct from--this is to delete w/c is my main intention
 SELECT * 
 FROM
  (
     (
        SELECT Rid,UID,ADDRESS,City,State,Zip,DataSource  
        FROM F_staRes where dataSource='Ohio'
     ) O inner join
     (
           SELECT Rid,UID,ADDRESS,City,State,Zip,DataSource  
           FROM F_staRes 
           where DataSource  in   ('Clev','Columbus')
     ) ct
          on O.UID=ct.UID and O.ADDRESS=ct.ADDRESS  and O.City=ct.City and   
          O.State=ct.State  and O.zip=ct.zip

            join dbo.ResOrig ro
            on ct.rId=ro.rId 

            join dbo.ResSta rs
            on ct.rId=rs.rId

            join dbo.ResDest rd 
            on ct.rId=rd.rId

           where ct.DataSource in ('Clev','Columbus')
```

Comment: Your question might be better migrated to [Code Review - Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) which is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

make sure   you have columns  to compare duplicates, and in order by column u have to keep asc or desc   here in your case  i written desc , first try  selecting the rows  by commenting delete statement  it will show the rows it gone a delete if you fine  just execute the script

```
;WITH tbl_online AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
PARTITION BY UID,ADDRESS,City,State,Zip ORDER BY DataSource  DESC) AS Rnum
FROM F_staRes)
--SELECT *  FROM tbl_online WHERE Rnum >1
DELETE   FROM tbl_online WHERE Rnum >1
```

Comment: ,Thank you for looking into my problem.Your suggestion does work but my issue is my join with the other tables,as I have 100k rec I have to use joins.And it doent let me to do delete because of fk constraint..Thanks again..I hope this makes a bit sense.

Comment: ohoo  you can do  like this , get  duplicate uid's into temp table  and delete in order means from child to parent